# How do I stop Twitter displaying URL contents?

Tags: twitter, unicode

If I tweet something containing wording that looks like (and is) a URL, but not intended to be interpreted as one, Twitter appends content from that URL to my tweet. I want to use the words ASP.NET without them being seen as a URL. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tweeting replace the dot symbol with it's ASCII value (& #046;) Twitter will then not convert your word into a hyperlink.

Comment: I was just testing, this does not seem to work using the web interface?

Comment: Didn't work on HootSuite either, but it's very close, I've found the answer. It's to add a zero length space after the period. `&#8203;`. This site will do it for you, scroll down a bit: http://www.labnol.org/internet/twitter-auto-converts-links/20771/